# Import from file in separate directory

Tags: python, flask, import

My flask application is one big lists of files right now and I am trying to divide it up into two primary folders, *app* and *spiders* so that it looks like this:

```
- app
  -- __init__.py
  -- app.py
  -- models.py
- spiders
  -- __init__.py
  -- scrape.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
```

The problem I am having is when trying to import my models into the scrape.py file.

When I try to import it absolutely with: 
`from app.models import Rate, Hotel, Location` I get the error `'no module named app'`. 
When I try to import relatively:
`from ..app.models import Rate, Hotel, Location` I get the error `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`. 
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: do you still have a `__init__.py` in the folder containing `App`?

Comment: Yes there is an ```__init__.py``` in the folder named app

Comment: try `from App` instead of `from app` (case sensitivity)

Comment: I apologize. I just edited the question but the folder names are already lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath, sep
sys.path.append(abspath(dirname(__file__) + sep + ".."))

import app.models as models
```

Note: This is really an ugly solution as it messes up your import block in the file. I suggest to add a main code file in the root folder like main.py and import spiders and app modules in there. You should not spread your flow controllers among files in sub folders

Comment: Thank you! Can you expand a bit on the proper solution? Say I create a main.py in the root folder. How would I import the models there, and then import those models from the scrape.py file?